# How to share code between controllers in adonis js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

can anyone suggest me how can I use a custom class for writing all helper methods so that the app doesn't repeat same code again and again in different controllers? How can I share codes between controllers? Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Ok I solved it. In case someone else is trying to solve it, here is how I solved

In `app` folder I created a folder named `Common`. Inside this folder I have a `index.js`. (`App/Common/index.js`) in this file I have

```
'use strict';

module.exports = class Help {
  display() {
    console.log('is it ok?')
  }
}
```

Now in my controllers I need to use it like this

```
var Help = use('App/Common')
```

In order to call the `display method` I need to call just like a normal OOP call

```
var obj = new Help();
obj.display();
```

That's it.